# Remove rows based on values in a column

Tags: csv, awk

I would like to remove all rows in my CSV where under the column "Owner" The Value is Fishbowl Digital Content.

Here is a sample CSV

```
ID,Name,Function,Media,Owner
415,Sam,Run,Footage,Production
213,Raj,Catch,Footage,Fishbowl Digital Content
214,Jack,Hold,Website,Salvage
256,Jason,Catch,Website,Fishbowl Digital Content
```

I have tried

```
awk -F , '$4 != "Fishbowl Digital Content" {print $0}' Test.csv >TestModified.csv
```

But I still see lines where the Value under "Owner" is 'Fishbowl Digital Content'

```
awk -F , '$4 != "Fishbowl Digital Content" {print $0}' Test.csv >TestModified.csv
```

Here are the desired Results:

```
ID,Name,Function,Media,Owner
415,Sam,Run,Footage,Production
214,Jack,Hold,Website,Salvage
```

Comment: if you count, it's the `$5`'th field.

Comment: @karakfa, that is why I added generic solution, where my solution finds out the field number of it(it can be any number) where owner is there and then it will check condition :)

Comment: @Saiyam Vora, Good that you have showed your efforts which you have puit to solve your issues. Try to use {} for wrapping your samples/commands in code tags too. Also give it sometime and when few answers are there for your question then try to select anyone of them as correct one too, happy learning

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not awk, but I find that the Miller way (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/) is very easy and useful

```
mlr --csv filter -x '$Owner=="Fishbowl Digital Content"' inputFile.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

***1st Solution(With hard-coding field value):*** Could you please try following.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1{print;next} $NF!="Fishbowl Digital Content"' Input_file
```

***2nd solution(Generic solution without hard-coding field value):*** Adding more generic solution in which it will check which field is having `Owner` value and then it will skipm lines. Meaning we are NOT hard coding value of `Owner` column here.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="Owner"){val=i}};print;next}  $val!="Fishbowl Digital Content"' Input_file
```

Comment: @Saiyam Vora, could you please do let me know if these solutions helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `grep` in case you are matching the first or the last column.  For the last column, here is the filter:

```
grep -v ',"Fishbowl Digital Content"$' file
```

If there could be trailing spaces, then:

```
grep -vE ',"Fishbowl Digital Content"[[:space:]]*$' file
```